# Custom suffix for specific product variation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, suffix

I am trying to add a suffix to the price of a variable item.
It only has to show when that specific item is selected.

I tried some different codes from stackoverflow, but all of the add the suffix to all variables instead of just the one I need.

Currently I am using following code, but it gives a critical error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WC_Product_Variation as array

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_price_custom_suffix', 10, 3 );
function variation_price_custom_suffix( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
// For a specific product variation ID
if( $variation['variation_id'] == 9256 ) {

    $variation_data['price_html'] .= ' ' . __("Text after price");
}

return $variation_data;
}
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a custom suffix for a specific product variation in WooCommerce, you can use:

```php
function variation_price_custom_suffix( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {   
    // For a specific product variation ID
    if ( $variation_data['variation_id'] == 9256 ) {
        $variation_data['price_html'] .= ' ' . __( 'Text after price', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $variation_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_price_custom_suffix', 10, 3 );
```