# Adding custom text after price of specific product variation in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a text after price of a specific product variation in Woocommerce. This is my code, but it's not working.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_price_custom_suffix', 10, 3 );
function variation_price_custom_suffix( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    global $post;      
    $product_id = $post->ID; 
    $product_array = array( 6547 ); //add in the product IDs to add text after price
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $product_array )){
    $variation_data['price_html'] .= ' <span class="price-suffix">' . __("TEST", "woocommerce") . '</span>';
}
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom suffix for specific product variation in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024517/custom-suffix-in-woocommerce-for-certain-variable)

Comment: @7uc1f3r it's perfect. Thanks a lot!!!